# GWTP Eclipse plugin generates empty presenters

Tags: java, eclipse, gwtp

I'm trying to create a GWTP sample app. There is a really [nice screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC-Qh4q1lCI), but I have to deal with a problem that didn't appear there (but, according to comments, some more newbies had to deal with errors). I use Eclipse Helios and a plugin [suggested here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/EclipsePlugin). Do I deal with incompatible versions?

When I generate the `WelcomePresenter`, there is nothing in `WelcomePresenter.java` and `WelcomeView.java` except the package strings. Also nothing is added in `ClientGinjector.java` and `ClientModule.java`. I tried to add everything that is needed by myself, but it's a bit hard because, well, I tried to create this app to understand how exactly GWTP works.

Could someone please provide the needed `WelcomePresenter.java` and `WelcomeView.java` (the other two classes in the `my.pack.client.gin` can be seen in the screencast, so it's not really a problem)? And what can be a reason for such Eclipse GWTP plugin behavior?

I'm not sure if it's a OS spesific problem, I tried to generate a presenter using Ubuntu.

**UPDATE**: I didn't face this problem when installed GWTP plugin in Eclipse using Ubuntu last time, which is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand GWTP, it is probably better to start without the Eclipse Plugin. It is like saying you want to learn Java and you are already using Eclipse. First things first, start from the beginning.

To create the view and presenters, simply follow the tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Using_GWTP).
If you want some more inspiration, take a look at the [examples](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/RunningGwtpSamples) which are fully working projects. It can help to familiarize yourself with the basic GWTP concepts.

If you are still stuck with them, then post code you have so far.

For the error you are seeing in the Eclipse plugin, I would suggest to contact GWTP members directly on their website. I have never used their plugin, so I cannot tell how it works what are the potential issues.

Comment: You are probably right, but installing the plugin is at the beginning of the GettingStarted part of their wiki.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, and as they state: _The rest of this document describes how to create a GWTP project manually step-by-step and will give you a *deep knowledge of GWTP's fundamental principles*_